# can't remember due to drinking

Tags: bitcoin-core

About 10 plus years ago, I was drinking heavily and decided to go online and buy some bitcoin. Since it wasn't worth much at the time, I just kind of forgot. But now I'm bummed that I can't recall what wallet I would have used. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might track this down. Can I possibly download some old bitcoin wallet that I can see if it recognized my email?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need the computer, disk or whatever device your wallet was stored on.

If you have that finding your wallet should be easy. Just search for it. How to do that depends on hardware, operating system and so on.